# what moment OR what scenario we use 'RETURN' key word in PROCEDURE in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

Hi can anyone give me some conceptual knowledge regarding my question.
what moment OR what scenario we use 'RETURN' key word in PROCEDURE in oracle 
Thanks

Comment: [To return control to the caller](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#CIHIIJEE)? I'm not sure I understand your question - what exactly are you confused about?

Answer (score 2):

Most often, when you want to exit a procedure early.  Whether this is a good idea or not is rather debatable-- there are good arguments to be made for preferring a single entry and exit point in all your methods.  On occasion, though, I find it reasonable to construct code with multiple exit points rather than nesting `IF` statements or trying to maintain some sort of state.

For example, imagine that I wanted to validate an attribute and that required applying a bunch of different business rules.  The caller wanted a flag returned and a message if the validation failed.  I might structure that to return as soon as one of those rules was violated.  Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE validate_name( p_name          IN varchar2,
                                           p_success_flag OUT boolean,
                                           p_error_msg    OUT varchar2 )
AS
  l_cnt_disallowed pls_integer;
BEGIN
  IF( p_name IS NULL )
  THEN 
    p_success_flag := false;
    p_error_msg := 'The name must be non-NULL';
    return;
  END IF;

  IF( length(p_name) > 50 )
  THEN 
    p_success_flag := false;
    p_error_msg    := 'The name must be <= 50 characters.';
    return;
  END IF;

  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO l_cnt_disallowed 
    FROM disallowed_names
   WHERE name = p_name;
  IF( l_cnt_disallowed > 0 )
  THEN
    p_success_flag := 0false
    p_error_msg    := 'The name must not be in the disallowed list.';
    return;
  END IF;    

  p_success_flag := true;
end;
```

Of course, you could implement this as an `IF/ ELSIF/ ELSIF/ ELSE` (or a `CASE`) with a single exit point.  That certainly works but it likely means that you have to do all the calculations (like the `select count(*)`) before the `IF` statement.  That may make the code less readable because the logic for a particular business rule is now in two different places so it's harder to see the full logic for each business rule.  You could potentially put the calculation in the `ELSIF` you want so that the logic remains together but then you end up with pretty deeply nested `IF` statements to ensure that a rule doesn't get skipped.

You could also add a flag (i.e. `l_found_error boolean := false`) that gets set to `true` whenever a rule is violated, subsequent `IF` statements could check that, and then there would be a single exit point for the method.  That's an entirely reasonable approach.  That adds one more state variable that you need to keep track of mentally and makes you do at least a quick validation that no one did something silly like reset the variable after it was set to `true`.  Personally, for this sort of thing, the benefit of being able to see from the `return` that no subsequent code is executed slightly outweighs the value of having a single return but that is a subjective opinion.

In this specific case, I'd rather have a function that returns an object with two fields or a procedure that throws an exception when a rule is violated over returning an error code but finding and parsing out the custom error message in the error stack and presenting that to a user may be rather more complicated than simply using an `OUT` parameter.